# DateTimeOffset: TZ Offset is reset to +00:00 when fetching data from LiteDb collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, litedb

When inserting, the offset is OK, however when retrieving the document, it's resetting to +00:00

Property:

```
public DateTimeOffset CreatedOn { get; set; }
```

Insert:

```
user.CreatedOn = DateTimeOffset.Now; // 01/20/2021 6:05:21 PM +05:30
col.Insert(user);
col.EnsureIndex(x => x.Username);
```

Find:

```
using (var db = _liteDbConnection.Create() as LiteDatabase)
{
   var col = db.GetCollection<AuthUser>(USERS_COLLECTION);
   return col.FindOne(x => x.UserId == userId);
}
```

`user.CreatedOn` becomes

`01/20/2021 6:05:21 PM +00:00`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does LiteDb support DateTimeOffset at all? From the [docs](https://www.litedb.org/docs/data-structure/) it looks like it only supports UTC `DateTime` even though it's stored using an offset

Comment: [LiteDB doesn't support DateTimeOffset](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/issues/1686) and from the comments, it doesn't look like the maintainers want to add support any time soon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.litedb.org/docs/data-structure/)

> Following the BSON specification, `DateTime` values are stored only up to the miliseconds. All `DateTime` values are converted to UTC on storage and converted back to local time on retrieval.

It doesn't look like there's actual `DateTimeOffset` support. (Personally I think it's a terrible idea to convert to local time on retrieval, but that's a slightly different matter.) Additionally, it looks like it's not *really* converting to local time properly, given the incorrect offset of 0.

I would suggest avoiding using `DateTimeOffset` with LiteDb until it's *really* supported (maintaining the offset).

Comment: Perhaps you can convert store the time as a timestamp which is a long. So store DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds() when you store the data and DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds() when  you retrieve it.

Comment: @GlennSills: That would certainly avoid the misleading information in the DateTimeOffset, yes. If the OP actually needs date/time and offset information, it looks like they'll need to store the offset in a separate database field.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because LiteDB stores a `DateTimeOffset` using `value.UtcDateTime`. This is unfortunate, but it can't be changed due to compatibility. However, you can override this behavior by creating a custom serializer:

```
BsonMapper.Global.RegisterType<DateTimeOffset>
(
    serialize: obj =>
    {
        var doc = new BsonDocument();
        doc["DateTime"] = obj.DateTime.Ticks;
        doc["Offset"] = obj.Offset.Ticks;
        return doc;
    },
    deserialize: doc => new DateTimeOffset(doc["DateTime"].AsInt64, new TimeSpan(doc["Offset"].AsInt64))
);
```